# Doing a Flash-style webcam site in Java

Tags: java, webcam

Would the following be possible in Java?

- Client A goes to a site and sends a live video stream from a webcam.
- Client B visits the same site and sees the video stream.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, but admittedly probably less pleasant than Flash. Check out [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) to capture the video; once you have it, you can just send it over a socket or something.